# AWS Lambda - max workers / threads for multithreading with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, aws-lambda, python-multithreading

I am collecting data for an analytics platform using AWS lambda Python and need to make several thousand API calls. I am using the multithreading module but I have no idea how many threads I should run in parallel.
It's legacy code Im working with and currently the function uses multiprocessing instead of multithreading (although those are I/O bound tasks) and runs 9 processes in parallel. I don't know where the "9" is coming from..

Comment: Why do you think it should be any different from what you used for `multiprocessing`? Odds are it was to limit concurrent connections/outstanding requests, but your documentation is the only place that could explain that number. If there is real CPU-bound work going on as well, it might be some number chosen to correspond to the number of cores you've paid for, or it could be the prior developer's favorite number. There is *no* answer we can give you that isn't a wild guess.

Comment: Hi @ShadowRanger, there is no documentation :/ In the code I can see that the number of CPUs is read (using some multiprocessing function, cpu_count() i think). However, the returned value (which is 2), is not used, instead '9' is used for number of parallel processes. Looking at the legacy code, I can only assume the person who wrote it, didnt know what they were doing and therefore I question the "9", but looking for an explanation or a suggestion, how to choose that value

Comment: Restricting execution to match the number of cores only makes sense in a CPU-bound `multiprocessing` scenario. In a threaded IO-bound scenario, most threads will be blocking most of the time, so exceeding the number of cores by some amount is perfectly reasonable. For all you know they tested and found that incremental gains disappeared above nine threads. You're welcome to test performance with other numbers, but there's no reason to assume IO-bound code should be limited to core count.